# C# Read pointer address value

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, memory-management, memory-address

(Sorry for my bad English )

How to read a value address from pointer in C#?

Example:
I know my pointer but the value change at application starting.

1) Start

```
(Pointer) 0x0018F36C   =  ( Value) 0x0342AD68
```

2) Restart

```
(Pointer) 0x0018F36C  = ( Value Changed ) 0x0342AE20
```

Actually i have a base address 0x0018F36C
but need to read value from pointer and save in long

example:

```
long addr_base = 0x0018F36C;
long address;  //Obviously I do not know the Address
```

now i need to read long value from  addr_base and put the value (long) in address

example

```
addr_base = memory.ReadAddress(addr_base)
```

anyone know how to read address stored in the variable called addr_base?

Comment: I'm very dubious as to why you are doing this... How do you get the value of the pointer in the first place? Does it come as a return value from an unmanaged function? There might be a better way to do this. (I'm predicting that you will try using `Marshal.ReadIntPtr()` but it won't do what you expect...)

Comment: Im get pointer from disassembler. I'm doing this to create a plugin to an application.

Comment: So you're trying to read memory from a different process? Is the application from which you got the pointer running in a separate process from your C# code? (I guess it must be...) If so, then this isn't going to work. Furthermore, the pointer is likely to change between runs.

Comment: Yes. the value of pointer change at run. But the address at pointer is same. dont change. Just need to obtain new addres value from the pointer

Comment: But you will not be able to use `Marshal.ReadIntPtr()` to read memory from another process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a an address like `0x0018F36C`, you can:

```
IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)0x0018F36C;
long longValue = Marshal.ReadInt64(ptr);
```

If from an address you need to read another address, there is another `Marshal` method:

```
IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)0x0018F36C;
IntPtr ptr2 = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr);
```

Comment: Hello xanatos tanks for help. the frist code work but the second example i have error type: Attempted to read or write protected memory . This is often an indication that other parts of memory are damaged .

Comment: @JoeMartiniello, The error is confusing, but it just means you are trying to do something invalid, like an address in memory that never was a valid address in the first place (you start with a fixed value, that is never right). Working and manipulating pointers from a managed application like C# requires a good understanding of marshalling and pinning of addresses, and knowing what `volatile` can do, to do right. Since you came from assembler, perhaps it is easier in your case to start out with C and C++ (even a mixed mode assembly, if you like), and write a wrapper. It'll feel easier.